# Logging values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components. App.js - Main. localLog.jsx stateless, LoadBoard.jsx statefull. I want to Take string of data from LoadBoard and display it in localLog.jsx. The  problem is that I can't figure it out why LocalLog is not displaying on screen.

`console.log(this.data.Array) in App.jsx localLog is ["configuration"]
(2) ["configuration", "It's good configuration"]`

App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.dataArray = [];
    this.state = {
      headers: []
    };
    this.localLog = this.localLog.bind(this);
  }

  localLog(data) {
    if (data) {
      this.dataArray.push(data);
      console.log(this.dataArray);
      this.dataArray.map(data => {
        return <LocalLog info={data} />;
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <LoadBoard apiBase={this.state.apiBase} localLog={this.localLog} />
        <pre id="log_box">{this.localLog()}</pre>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

localLog.jsx

```
let localLog = props => {
  return (
    <pre className={classes.background}>
      <ul className={classes.ul}>
        <li>{props.info}</li>
        <li>hello world</li>
      </ul>
    </pre>
  );
};

export default localLog;
```

LoadBoard.jsx

```
class LoadBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      positionToId: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.localLog("configuration");
    this.props.localLog(`It's good configuration`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Nothing interesting</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are expecting some data and you don't pass any. Is this intentional? Also you don't return the map result to render.

Comment: @AlexG Not sure I follow you. What do you mean by "You are expecting some data and you don't pass any"?

Comment: In localLog you have a condition if (data) { ... }. From the render you are calling the function without any parameters. {this.localLog()}

Comment: Yes if I call a function with a parameter, I {this.localLog(data)} I get data is not defined. And since data is in LoadBoard, i don't have it in App.jsx. Unless I could pass an empty string called data.

Comment: You should call the function with the data you want to log. Not just a variable named data (which will raise an error if not defined). What are you trying to log?

Comment: I'm trying to display log. So When LoadBoard.jsx componentDidMount method activates, I want to display in LocalLog screen LoadBoard activated or in this case configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the `localLog` method, should be:

```
return this.dataArray.map(data => {
    return <LocalLog info={data} />;
});
```

EDIT:

here is what your App component should look like.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      headers: [],
      logs: []
    };
    this.addLog = this.addLog.bind(this);
  }

  // Add log to state
  addLog(log) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      logs: [...state.logs, log]
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <LoadBoard apiBase={this.state.apiBase} localLog={this.addLog} />
        <pre id="log_box">
          {this.state.logs.map(log => {
            return <LocalLog info={log} />;
          })}
        </pre>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely step in correct direction. But It's still not displaying. <LocalLog /> component displays fine. Something still wrong with my method.

Comment: @ArnasDičkus I added the entire App component code now that you have clarified what your idea behind this is.

Answer (score 2):

you should use **setState** method in order to re-render the component.
you can try this.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      headers: [],
      dataArray: []
    };
    this.localLog = this.localLog.bind(this);
  }

  localLog(data) {
    if (data) {
      this.state.dataArray.push(data);
      this.setState({dataArray: this.state.dataArray})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <LoadBoard apiBase={this.state.apiBase} localLog={this.localLog} />
        <pre id="log_box">{this.state.dataArray.map(i => <LoaclLog info={i}/>)}</pre>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```